# Push siblings out of view while keeping their width

Tags: css, flexbox, transition

When hovering a flex element i now set the flex-basis to 100%. While doing this all siblings get resized to a width of 0 (i think) and this is showing in the animation.

Is it possible (preferred with just css) to let these sibling keep their width (nr of siblings is variable so in some scenarios there will be more columns then the example below) while the element that is hovered is expanding to 100% width? So that it looks as if they where pushed out of the container instead of resized to a width of 0.

Here is how it works now: https://jsfiddle.net/luffyyyyy/y8p9g2bs/8/

```
.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.day-container {
    flex: 1; 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: flex-basis 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.day-container:hover {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

Comment: did you tried `transform:scale()` ??. Try replacing `flex-basis` with `
    -webkit-transform: scale(9, 1);`

Comment: Hi Akhil, i did try this before. This makes it so the hovered day-container overlaps/ignores it's siblings, so they stay in their place. Not the effect i'm looking for.

Comment: @awsome-o you need to add `transition:.5s` to both `.day-container` and `.day-container:hover{}` to get a smooth effect. Did you try that

Comment: @AkhilAravind It's not about the effect being smooth, it is/was smooth enough. When you look at the fiddle you'll see when hovering one of the columns the other columns will collapse (resize to a width of 0px). Now what i want instead is that the other columns to not collapse but move out of view while keeping their width. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Awesom-o Do you want the other elements stay in the same position with the same width? or you want to move them out of the view in other position but with the same width?

Comment: https://codepen.io/wifeo/pen/qzwkb , like this ??

Comment: @AlbertoRhuertas the ladder (in other position but with the same width). It should look like so they get pushed out of view.

Comment: @Awesom-o got it. Do you can use `grid` instead of `flex` for the container? I think this is not posible with `flex` and only CSS (may be I'm wrong). For sure, you can do it with JS and playing with the `position` and `width`.

Comment: @Awesom-o do you know in advance how many `.day-container` items you will have or should this be a universal solution that works in different scenarios?

Comment: @AlbertoRhuertas I'm gonna use js before grid if this doesn't work out.

Comment: @mizurnix Good point, there will be scenarios where there will be more then 5 columns. Added this to my first post ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what could achieve so far. But for this to work you must know the number of sibling elements, in your case the `.day-container`. So, from your jsfiddle there are total of 5 `.day-container` elements so the `100/5 = 20%` should be the `flex-bases` for `.day-container` elements.

now we will move all the `.day-container` elements before the **hovered** one to left by 20% when `.container` has hovered with the help of `general sibling selector '~'` . Here's the code:

```
.container:hover .day-container:not(:hover) {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

.container:hover .day-container:hover ~ .day-container {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

finally, change `transition` to `all` for everything to move smoothly.
This is how the final code should look like:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.day-container {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.day-container:hover {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.item.small {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.item.medium {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
.item.big {
  flex: 3;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

.container:hover .day-container:not(:hover) {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

.container:hover .day-container:hover ~ .day-container {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i need to play around with this idea more when i got time. The way you posted it doesn't work, it seems only the first sibling to the left of the hovered day-container keeps his width.. the rest still collapses. See: https://jsfiddle.net/luffyyyyy/y8p9g2bs/18/

Comment: Hi, I just realized that I had made a mistake in my previous code. It was supposed to be a `general sibling selector` instead of `adjacent selector`. Please check now if this works as your requirement. I hope it solves your issue :)

Comment: Just wanted to go and play around with this but you got it this way :) Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the farthest I've gotten, but I believe to get the centering right, you'll have to employ Javascript:

https://jsfiddle.net/xum8va4t/

it works by adding a second `flexbox` wrapper that grows on hover just like the day-container